# Is there an easy way to do an "inline" compare of sections inside a file (like interfaces in a cisco config file)?

Tags: comparison, configuration-files, cisco

In a Cisco configuration file for a switch each port has its own section.  That section describes how that port is configured.

Is there a way to compare all of those sections - based either on all ports total, or by blade.

Here is one port for an example:
interface GigabitEthernet3/5
 description 6509l1007-3/05
 switchport
 switchport access vlan 660
 switchport mode access
 mtu 9216
 no logging event link-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 spanning-tree portfast
!

The next port would be "interface GigabitEthernet3/6".

I am looking for a way to see what settings are common and which settings are unique.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there are no tools built-in to do this.

You can use `show running-config all` to display the default settings as well as those explicity configured; this would at least give you a standard number of output lines per interface which could be compared more easily.

If your AAA setup allows it, you might try something like [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (command-line interface to putty) which would allow you to script connection, login and execution of commands os the switch.  The resulting output could be saved for analysis or dealt with in the script.